# Upload images problem: IO error. (Error #2038)

Tags: uploadify

I'm using script which is uploading files to server via flash component. Sometimes, very rarely, when trying to upload images via Firefox I get following error: IO error #2038. Searching on the net I could find reason why is it really happening to me. But I found solution for my case:
I open IE6, do the same thing there (photos are always uploaded without problem) and the when I try again in Firefox problem disappears. If someone had similar problems maybe this could help or maybe this hint could help to someone discovering cause of the problem :)

Comment: If you are using MVC and if you use `HttpPostedFile` class in controller parameter it causes IO Error. replace it with `HttpPostedFileBase `

Answer (score 1):

After far more time than I'd like to admit, here is the solution.  Change the following variables in your `php.ini` to be large enough to handle your largest file:

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept. 
post_max_size = 32M

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 32M

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads. (this is on by default)
file_uploads = On
```

Since files are sent as POST data, **both** the first variables need to be set. Otherwise, there will be an error, but you won't see what the error is, except `IO error #2038`.

Comment: I saw this solution, but none of my images I tried to upload were bigger than 1mb, so I don't think the size was the problem

Answer (score 1):

I just had this error also using ASP.Net MVC and I discovered I just had my handler namespace wrong/missspellled in the web config section where the handlers go. HTH...

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't add quote around the option names, try doing that.  Sometimes in IE, quoting the option names fixes the issue.  It would help if you posted some example code though.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

In my office I use a proxy and I must change the settings to `No Proxy`.

Or if you do not use proxy, try to change in `php.ini`:

```
Hostname:Port localhost:0
```

to:

```
Hostname:Port localhost:80
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that the path to the server being used by the upload component is correct.  If the path is a relative path, try to fully qualify it.  IE can do some "magic" with relative paths that the other browsers cannot do, and sometimes trying the code from one browser to the other can tweak things.

Also, could be permissions...and having IE go there first could manipulate the permissions in a way that the other browser(s) then work "correctly".